# Find the relative position of a famo.us Surface

Tags: famo.us

Is there a way to get the current position of a [famo.us](http://www.famo.us) Surface?

I mean, after the render tree has done its thing and all modifiers have been multiplied, the surface exists somewhere on the screen. But I can't figure out how to just ask where. Seems a simple enough question.

Specifically, I'm building a kind of scroll view and need to test if a contained surface has moved outside of a bounding box.

It looks like the surface itself has a `_matrix` property that I could use, but this seems a crude way of doing it.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's also seemingly impossible to natively know when all surfaces had been rendered for a layout, which is a related problem. See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681117/what-is-a-good-way-to-know-when-all-surfaces-had-been-initially-rendered-in-famo) on that.